# añadir api de google maps en pagina jspx

Tags: javascript, google-maps, spring-mvc

He intentado agregar la api de google maps en un .jspx.

```html
<div id="test_page_1" class="body_container" 
xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:tiles="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles">
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<jsp:directive.page pageEncoding="UTF-8" />

<div id="map"><jsp:text/></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIsaaSiCKkCoayQP8JuignmM4mQMjzjpykQ&callback=initMap">
</script>  
</div>
```

Y no he logrado hacer que funcione. Siempre saca error por el caracter '&' que va luego de callback.
El error se presente justo cuando se agrega el script de la api, y al parecer es porque jspx no soporta el caracter & que está justo antes de la función callback

```html
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIsaaSiCKkCoayQP8JuignmM4mQMjzjpykQ&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de poder cargar la api sin que me genere este problema.

Comment: hola julian, veo que tu problema esta en la propiedad src, no estas especificando una Key para el uso de la API, desconozco cuando se implemento esto, pero ahora para usar una API, necesitas solicitar una Key
Enlace : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=ES

Comment: si claro, me faltó comentar que ya tengo la api, es solo que la puse así como prueba. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Te da error tras el "&" que indica que ejecute la función initMap tras cargar el mapa. Si no tienes definida esa función el mapa no te cargará.

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de la funcion initMap:

```
<script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias @jose por tu respuesta. Si, ya tengo el callback, solo puse la parte donde se importa la api, porque ahí es donde me está generando problema. Ya puse en la pregunta toda la página jspx.

Answer (score -1):

debes de remplazar en la linea del script '&' por el  '&'
example:

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APiKey_here&amp;callback=initMap"/>
```